# How create service provider (singleton)?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have such function which create new connection when I call it:

```
public function newBaseQueryBuilder()
{
   ...
   $host = config('sphinx.connection.host');
   $port = config('sphinx.connection.port');
   $pdo = new \PDO("mysql:host={$host};port={$port};", '', '');
   $connection = new SphinxConnection($pdo);
   ...
}
```

Have create service provider which create only one connection?

Answer (score 0):

Bind the class as a [singleton](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/container#binding):

```
$this->app->singleton('SphinxConnection', function ($app) {
    $host = config('sphinx.connection.host');
    $port = config('sphinx.connection.port');
    $pdo = new \PDO("mysql:host={$host};port={$port};", '', '');
    return new SphinxConnection($pdo);
});
```

Inject it via a constructor or method and use. Or inject it manually:

```
$connection = app('SphinxConnection');
```